# JQuery Autocomplete #combobox not working with jquery DataTables

Tags: css, jquery-ui, datatables

Requirement : I need editable drop down in my application similar to the one in the given [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox).

In my existing application I am  using jQuery Data table within this table I need one of the column to be editable drop down.

For this I Googled it and found jQueryUI AutoComplete ComboBox,I gone through the demo and I changed it according to my requirement but I didn't find any changes.

Even I am not able to understand whether cause/problem is ude to Data Table or jQueryUI/autocomplete library.

FYI,
I have included

1. jquery-ui.js
2. jquery.dataTables.min.js (datatable)
3. js/jquery-1.9.1.js
4. css/style.css

if any one come across this problem please guide me.

Comment: The error must be in implementation, cause jquery autocomplete works for sure. Try to insert the example from their demo and see what happens. People cannot answer you, because you haven't provided enough data. By the way, is the `css/style.css` the `jquery-ui.css`?

Comment: What is your problem exactly? How did you tried to integrate the dropdown inside the datatable? Do you use server side processing? Can you provide the demo what you tried to change according to your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Before configure this in your application ,please try this in a different file. i have tried this code  and works . May be some other script files in your application affected this JQ.